# Create a +1 Animation when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a game where you get money for clicking on a button. Here's a part of it:

```js
var money = 0;
var currentMoney = document.getElementById("currentMoney");

function addOne() {
  money++;
  currentMoney.innerHTML = money;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addOne();">+1$</button>
<p>Money: <b id="currentMoney">0</b>$</p>
```

Later i was looking in the Internet and i found a website called Cookie Clicker and i saw this animation that when you click the cookie,  a +1 is going up and fades away (It is not so important that the number goes up where the mouse is for my example):

[image]

I tried making this animation but i don't know how i can make it go up:

```js
var money = 0;
var currentMoney = document.getElementById("currentMoney");

function addOne() {
  money++;
  currentMoney.innerHTML = money;
  
  var moneyAnimation = document.createElement("p");
  moneyAnimation.innerHTML = "+1";
  document.getElementById("moneyAnimation").appendChild(moneyAnimation);
  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#moneyAnimation {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addOne();">+1$</button>
<p>Money: <b id="currentMoney">0</b>$</p>

<div id="moneyAnimation"></div>
```

Thanks in advance, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using CSS animation like below.
You can read more about keyframe animation [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

```js
var money = 0;
var currentMoney = document.getElementById("currentMoney");

function addOne() {
  money++;
  currentMoney.innerHTML = money;

  var moneyAnimation = document.createElement("p");
  moneyAnimation.innerHTML = "+1";
  document.getElementById("moneyAnimation").appendChild(moneyAnimation);
  moneyAnimation.classList.add("moneyAnimation"); // Add the class that animates
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#moneyAnimation {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}

@keyframes moneyAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: -50px;
  }
}

.moneyAnimation {
  animation: moneyAnimation 1s forwards;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addOne();">+1$</button>
<p>Money: <b id="currentMoney">0</b>$</p>
<div id="moneyAnimation"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Gerard, this works really good! But how can i hide the "+1" when the button is clicked? Right now it's displayed when the animation is over

Comment: @JustChillinInDaHood I adjusted the CSS class slightly, adding **forwards** to the code.